# place an alt tag for a flash image

Tags: html, flash

Hi 
I have a flash file. Which contain images. I want to place an ALT tag for the animated flash. Is it possible to place an ALT tag for flash?

Please give me a solution

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as an alt tag, it is an *attribute*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternative content for objects (for when they fail to load) goes between `<object>` and `</object>`.

If the Flash does load, then any alternative content needs to be exposed to accessibility APIs from inside the Flash object. Screen readers, braille displays, etc can then access it.

WebAIM has a guide to [making Flash content as accessible as possible](http://webaim.org/techniques/flash/).